# Exercise with differential of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, projective-space

Let $f:\mathbb{ RP}\to\mathbb{ RP}^2$ such that $f([x_1:x_2])=[x_1^2:x_1x_2:x_2^2]$; I have to show that the function is $C^\infty$ and find the differential in any point.

I decided to use these charts for $\mathbb{ RP}$: $$\varphi_1:U_1\to \mathbb R , \ \ \varphi_1([x_1:x_2])=\frac {x_2} {x_1}$$ $$\varphi_2:U_2\to \mathbb R , \ \ \varphi_2([x_1:x_2])=\frac {x_1} {x_2}$$ where $U_1=\mathbb{ RP}\backslash\{[0:1]\}$ and $U_2=\mathbb{ RP}\backslash\{[1:0]\}$. I used these charts for $\mathbb{ RP}^2$: $$ \phi_1:W_1\to\mathbb{ RP}^2, \ \ \phi_1([y_1:y_2:y_3])=\left( \frac{y_2} {y_1},\frac{y_3} {y_1}\right)$$ where $W_1=\mathbb{ RP}^2\backslash\{[0:a:b]\}$ with $a,b\neq 0$, and similarly I defined $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$.

To show that is $C^\infty$ we can calculate $\phi_1\circ f \circ \varphi_1^{-1} $ and $\phi_3\circ f \circ \varphi_2^{-1}$, since $f(\mathbb{ RP})\subset U_1\cup U_3$; I obtained $\phi_1\circ f \circ \varphi_1^{-1}(s) =\phi_3\circ f \circ \varphi_2^{-1}(s)=\left(s^2,s\right)$, that is clearly $C^\infty$ in every component. However I don't understand what does it mean to find the differential in the coordinates of $\mathbb{ RP}^2$; can you give me an explanation? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint, not an answer**

The differential at any point $p \in \Bbb R \Bbb P$ is a linear map from $T_p {\Bbb RP}$ to $T_{f(p)} {\Bbb RP}^2$. And you just *know* that somehow it's going to involve taking a derivative of $(s^2, s)$ with respect to *something*, probably $s$, but the exact details are a little vague at present.

But as a first step, you need to decide how you're going to describe elements of each of those tangent spaces. If you don't have a way to do that, then there's really no way to express a function between them.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated the typology of answer; however I basically don't understand of what coordinates we are speaking about. I mean, if we take a simple example like $i:S^1\hookrightarrow S^2$, what would be the differential of $i$ in the coordinates of $S^2$?

Comment: The differential would have to be expressed in the coordinates of both the domain $S^1$ and the codomain $S^2$, and in fact, in terms of the coordinates on the tangent spaces of $S^1$ and $S^2$ at the relevant points. If  $P : M \to R^k$ is a coordinate chart at some point $m \in M$, then there are vectors called (oddly enough) $\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial P_i} \right|_m$, for $i = 1, \ldots, k$, which form a basis for $T_m M$...but there's no room here to fully define them. If your text/notes don't tell you about coordinates on the tangent space, that's not something I can fix here.